# Angular: Can't inject store into service

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I am trying to inject a store into a service, but I am receiving the following error:

> Cannot read property 'select' of undefined

This is being raised on this line:

```
this.authUser$ = this.store.select(GetAuthUser);
```

For some reason, the framework is having difficulty creating the store. The whole constructor of the service looks like this:

```
constructor(private store: Store<State>) {
  super();

  this.authUser$ = this.store.select(GetAuthUser);
}
```

The `State` looks like this:

```
export interface State {
  navigation: fromNavigation.State;
  router: RouterReducerState;
  auth: fromAuth.State;
}
```

I have tried being more specific with the `State` and using just the `authState.State`, but this doesn't work.

I have used the same code in a component, using the same state `Store<State>` in the constructor, and it works fine. It's just using it in a service is the problem.

I'm sure it's something pretty simple, but I can't figure it out. What could be wrong? Do you need any more information?

Comment: Thanks @Igor, but I don't know how to do that. Could you please post some code or a link that describes this? It's a service, so I'm guessing it would have to be at module level.

Comment: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#registering-root-state

Comment: Oh. I'm already importing the store using `StoreModule.forRoot(fromStore.reducers, {metaReducers})`. Any other ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: Have you tried just this.authUser$ = this.store.select(‘auth’). Does that return a value for authUser$?

Comment: It's the `store` that is undefined. So `this.store.select()` fails, no matter what the format of the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out I was being an idiot.

The service that had the store in its constructor was not being created by DI, it was being created in a factory. Now I need to work out how to inject the store into a factory!

Comment: I have a factory on the app module that I inject the Store into by adding the dependency in the provider: `deps: [[new Inject(Store)]],`